# X-Robot-tag noindex not appearing in header

Tags: apache, linux

I am trying to include the following in my response header to all resources in multiple directories (dirone/dirtwo/dirthree/direfour) from an Apache server.

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

In my httpd.conf file I have added the setting to the dirone underneath my main directory declaration.

It is not producing the additional item in the response header. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/web/sitename/docs/dirone">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Directory>
```

Additional information. I am moving away from the robots.txt approach, we do not use .htaccess files and I want the header in all resources in those directories and their sub-directories to have X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow in them as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to confirm, is `/web/sitename/docs/dirone` a physical directory (or symlink) on the filesystem?

Comment: It is the physical directory

Comment: The syntax above did work once the /dev/ was added to the path. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the `Header` directive shouldn't go in a `Directory` section.   Instead it should go with the other configuration for `sitename` and use a `Files` directive.

So in your `sitename` configuration (even in your .htaccess) you should use:

```
<Files "dirone/*">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```

Comment: The `Header` directive is permitted in `<Directory>` sections and this can certainly work. So it would seem there is _something else_ going on here?

Comment: @w3d   Right, something else must be going on.

Comment: Thanks. it was something else. The path I used was incorrect.

Comment: @wall-nut I know it's an old question, but look at my answer and see if it's ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/dirone.* NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/dirtwo.* NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/dirthree.* NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/direfour.* NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
```